# Questions about other ARM-based computer?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about other ARM devices appropriate ?
Like NVIDIA Tegra 2 – a dual-core ARM Cortex A9 based or others ?

Are ARM-based computers (not phones) right (or wrong) in general for this site or are there additional criteria ?

Answer (score 5):

To quote the [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37041?phase=definition)

> Q&A site for users and developers of hardware and software for
>   Raspberry Pi

At the moment the site is for RPi. That doesn't mean it can't change over time if that seems appropriate, or if there isn't enough to sustain an RPi specific site.

I guess it depends a little on whether the RPi itself really takes off. If it goes like the foundation is planning then there will be a lot of users finding their way out there who will need specialized help, and input on novel RPi based projects.

Answer (score 3):

Other specific ARM devices are off topic at this stage.

However, if there is a question that relates to the Pi but is useful to a wider family of devices too, I don't see that being an issue.