# Beyond Raspberry Pi?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to expand the scope of our Raspberry Pi SE site to include other, similar single-board computers?

Comment: It's been discussed [before](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/567/19949) (and [related](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/738/19949)) but there is nothing wrong in going over the old arguments again and re-evaluate. Merry christmas.

Comment: OK - I called myself looking before posting, but apparently wasn't thorough :P Anyway... FWIW, since those questions, Arduino has their own site now, and IMHO, it is "too different" from RPi to make a "merger" practical. However, there are a number of SBCs that a) run Linux, and b) provide IO for controlling external devices. BeagleBone (maybe others?) even use ARM processors. What would have to be done to enlarge the scope? Would it dilute resources/reduce answer quality to expand?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer right now, but here are some previous discussions on this topic in historical order, most recent first (there are probably more, I have not finished looking):

- [Where would you post questions about boards like BeagleBone, pcDuino](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/738/where-would-you-post-questions-about-boards-like-beaglebone-pcduino)
- [What would you think about broadening the topic to include Arduino, Robotics and Embedded Systems in general?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/what-would-you-think-about-broadening-the-topic-to-include-arduino-robotics-and)
  This one was posted a day after:
- [are banana/orange/etc. questions on topic?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/566/are-banana-orange-etc-questions-on-topic)
- [Can we ask questions related to banana pi here?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/can-we-ask-questions-related-to-banana-pi-here)
- [Should this site merge with the Embedded Programming & Design Proposal?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/should-this-site-merge-with-the-embedded-programming-design-proposal)
- [Questions about other ARM-based computer?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/questions-about-other-arm-based-computer)
- [Can we rename this site to be more inclusive of Linux ARM hardware?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/can-we-rename-this-site-to-be-more-inclusive-of-linux-arm-hardware)

Briefly, this is something I wanted to see happen (allow all dev boards) up to and slightly beyond my first becoming a moderator here 5-6 years ago, until a couple of people convinced me otherwise.  I'll take time to summarize why I still feel that way later -- all this *doesn't* mean I think further discussion is not worthwhile.

Comment: Good answer (non-answer? :)... you've captured the essence (or at least the history) of the discussion. And it's an interesting discussion with valid pros and cons. IMHO, the oldest & the newest questions/discussion cover the salient issues most clearly. I'd like to try the 'expansion', but perhaps limited to one or two boards. My arguments boil down to this: 1. The 'character' of this site is well-suited to a bit of scope increase, 2. We don't strictly follow the 'exclusive RPi' charter now, 3. Some (me for exmpl) find RPi itself growing a bit stale; we could be about 'solutions' instead of -

Answer (score 2):

Banana, Orange & Orange all have their own websites and Forums. Beaglebone (despite its apparent popularity) doesn't seem to have even this.

What they lack is a group of dedicated users (at least to judge from their websites)

They are all derivatives, attempting to piggyback on the RaspberryPi popularity.
They may have some advantages in hardware, but little, if any, software support.

We all support (directly or indirectly) the Foundation's work by purchasing hardware, subscribing to publications etc. If people want to make use of RaspberryPi hardware or software the answer is simple - buy a Pi.

There is nothing wrong with these devices, but you have to ask **what would questions about these boards add to this site**?

Already the majority of questions on this site are strictly off-topic (Linux questions, 3rd party hardware, electronics questions, general "design my project for me questions" etc).

The last thing we need is a set of questions about how to adapt RaspberryPi solutions to incompatible hardware. The few questions we get about these platforms (before they are closed) seem to be low quality and lacking research.

Any questions about ARM processors would probably be OK, but these are rare.

PS Many of the links ask where you can get support for these other fruit - it is not our responsibility to find support for their chosen hardware.

Comment: Hmm... "support the Foundation's work"? Maybe that's something that you wish to do, but that's not what I'm doing here. I'm here only because it's a congenial environment mostly, and most importantly: I learn. And since you ask, I think that these boards could add ***diversity*** here; the hardware diffs certainly open up possibilities for new/improved solutions. I know I'd learn and benefit from these differences.

Comment: Minor point: *"They are all derivatives.."* Not sure if you intended to include beagleboard in that but it was around for a number of years before the Pi.