# Moderator closed a topic when it shouldn't have been, how to get reopened?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange post: [Multiple HDDs with Orange Pi NAS Expansion Board?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109678/multiple-hdds-with-orange-pi-nas-expansion-board)

I posted a question earlier today, and it soon got closed by a moderator. This is what he said-

"Note that even if you tweaked this to focus on the Pi, shopping requests are still off-topic here. Questions such as "what operating system to use for an NAS" are primarily opinion based, which does not our Q&A format (so off topic again). Objective questions such as "Can I use Acme OS to create an NAS with a Raspberry Pi?" are fine." – goldilocks♦ 3 hours ago

He also sent this link- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

My question follows the rules in this though. I copied the following from that link. Words in bold are added by me.

If your question is about: Raspberry Pi hardware, including GPIO and other related electronics. The first part of the question is just asking if certain adapters will work with a Orange Pi, which is basically an off brand Raspberry Pi. That part of the question falls under this. Raspberry Pi peripherals. Software specific to the Raspberry Pi. Operating Systems built for the Raspberry Pi. The second part of my question falls under this. All I am asking is, would a operating system made specifically for a NAS, or a normal operating system such as Linux or Ubuntu be better? Or would both work just as well? Materials published or provided by the Raspberry Pi Foundation. … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But please note that the following is off topic Raspberry Pi orders or delivery. Asking for specific purchasing recommendations: This refers to questions such as, "What power supply should I buy?" (= off-topic). However, if you have a specific product and you want to know if it is suitable for a specific purpose ("Is this power supply okay for a Pi Zero W?"), that's fine. Asking what to look for in a kind of product is also fine ("What is the minimum amperage power supply I can use with the Pi 3?"). Asking for references to online material (use a search engine, and if that does not work, ask about the issue directly). Raspberry Pi accessories relating exclusively to appearance (such as cases). Questions directly related to Linux/Unix issues. Please use the Unix & Linux Exchange. General programming questions, e.g., "How do I implement a keyboard interrupt in python?". These will be better off on Software Engineering or Stack Overflow.

And that is all of my question. How should I get it reopened? I already reported the comment saying why they closed it. I need an answer ASAP. Should I repost the question and include a link to this, or would that get me kicked out of Stack Exchange? Thanks!

Comment: Orange Pis are not just some variant of the Raspberry Pi neither are Banana Pis or any other fruit... and they are off-topic here. No amount of rule lawyering is going to change that.

Comment: Where can I ask this question on stack exchange then? There is not an orange pi stack exchange community, and this is the closest I could find.

Comment: I am not entirely sure which stack would be appropriate (not that I don't follow most of them them), [Hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a place to start with respect to the search for the hardware.

Comment: Orange Pi is **NOT** an off brand Raspberry Pi - it is a cheap rip-off attempting to ride on the tails of Raspberry Pi but with little official support, documentation and no supporting user community. Why don't you start one?

Comment: ok, I will try the hardware recommendations one, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to find that the off-topic help page does not explicitly say questions about banana/orange/strawberry/vanilla pis are off-topic,<sup>1</sup> because it has been a very explicitly enforced policy since the site began.

I'm not going to debate that policy here. I was against it a long time ago, previous to being a moderator, but I/we were in a minority, so it stuck.  Later I came to be persuaded of the wisdom of it.  The last discussion of it here was not long ago:

[Beyond Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2202/5538)

Where I posted a list of links to the previous discussions.  I am not so against the policy that I would fight tooth and nail to prevent changing it, but part of my role here is to represent and work for the community that elected me, and I am pretty sure, given all the opportunities there have been for us to rally together and make such a decision, that it is not going to happen; the majority would in the end still say no.<sup>2</sup>

> The first part of the question is just asking if certain adapters will work

You are right; my comment about the shopping request was, on a more attentive reading, off base.  If this were about the Raspberry Pi, that would be okay.

The "what operating system to use" in a context where any number of them would do just as well because most of them likely use the exact same software stack underneath will always be about people expounding the virtues of their favourite things.  That's great and has legitimate value, but it simply does not work with an objective Q&A format.  **We are not trying to be all things to all people**.  If I wanted to start a discussion of that sort, I wouldn't do it here, I'd use reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/OrangePI/

Which is *also* a great place to find technical expertise in a more free-flowing format. I notice too there's an official Orange Pi forum:

http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php

Which looks to be "discussion style" (which we are not). They are both active (and these are things I did not even have to try to find).  You have some specific questions about some specific hardware and the best thing for you to do is find the people who use that hardware and ask them about it.

---

1. That's been fixed, and all apologies for wasting your time.
2. It might be worth noting that there have also been a number of attempts in the Stack Exchange network to set up sites parallel to this one for dev boards in general that did not make it through beta testing.  But something which did succeed and *does* take Orange Pi questions is:

https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps a lot. I was also thinking the same, maybe someone should start a general single-board computer community. I tried to get into the Orange Pi forum before, but they made me wait a while before I could ask questions. By this time they are letting me, so I will ask my question there. Like you said, I might check out the IOT community and see what questions they take, and maybe ask the question there. My main issue was that you were closing the topic explaining why it was closed incorrectly, and that it doesnt say I cant ask what I was asking, so thanks for fixing that.